# Table or view does not exist | PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Currently I am trying to write a PLSQL code.

Question :
Need to find first 5 highest marks student from table students and push to another table

Need to implement using cursor but throwing error. Can sometime help me to resolve error

**My code:**

```
DECLARE

    v_table_name VARCHAR2(250) := 'V_STUDENTS';
    v_cnt        NUMBER;
    v_sql        CLOB;
    
    CURSOR c1 IS SELECT  *  FROM  STUDENTS ORDER BY student_marks DESC;

        TYPE v_stud
        IS
          RECORD
          (
            v_id students.student_id%TYPE,
            v_name students.student_name%TYPE,
            v_marks students.student_marks%TYPE );
            
        v_temp V_STUD;
          
BEGIN

     SELECT
        COUNT(*)
     INTO v_cnt
     FROM
        all_tables
     WHERE
        table_name = v_table_name;
  
  IF TRIM(v_cnt) = 0 THEN

    v_sql := 'CREATE TABLE V_STUDENTS AS SELECT * FROM ' || v_table_name || ' WHERE 1=2; ';
    
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
    
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_sql);
   
    OPEN c1;
    
            FOR i IN 1..5
            LOOP
            
              FETCH c1 INTO v_temp;
              
              EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
              
              INSERT INTO V_STUDENTS VALUES
                          (
                                      v_temp.v_id,
                                      v_temp.v_name,
                                      v_temp.v_marks
                          );
              
              COMMIT;
              
              dbms_output.Put_line('Record inserted successfully : ' || c1%rowcount);
              
            END LOOP;
            
    CLOSE c1;
    
  ELSE
  
    OPEN c1;
    
            FOR i IN 1..5
            LOOP
              FETCH c1
              INTO  v_temp;
              
              EXIT
            WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
            
              INSERT INTO V_STUDENTS VALUES
                          (
                                      v_temp.v_id,
                                      v_temp.v_name,
                                      v_temp.v_marks
                          );
              
              COMMIT;
              
              dbms_output.put_line('Record inserted successfully : ' || c1%rowcount);
              
            END LOOP;
    
    CLOSE c1;
    
  END IF;
  
EXCEPTION
        WHEN 
            OTHERS 
                  THEN 
                      dbms_output.put_line('Error occurred : ' || SQLERRM);
                
end;
```

Expecting first 5 highest marks student details in v_students table

**error occurred in my code:**

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 48, column 27:

PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

ORA-06550: line 48, column 15:

PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

ORA-06550: line 75, column 27:

PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

ORA-06550: line 75, column 15:

PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"

*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.

*Action:
```

Comment: `'CREATE TABLE V_STUDENTS AS SELECT * FROM ' || v_table_name || ' WHERE 1=2; '` shall probably be `'CREATE TABLE ' || v_table_name || ' AS SELECT * FROM students WHERE 1=2'`, i.e. you confused the two tables and must remove the semicolon from the SQL string.

Comment: `TRIM(v_cnt)` makes no sense by the way. v_cnt is a number and `TRIM` is a string function. What you are doing here is to implicitly convert the number 0 or 1 into a string '0' or '1', which you then unnecessarily trim, and then you convert the string '0' or '1' back to 0 or 1 in order to compare it with 0.

Comment: I doubt that you get that code compiled anyway. You have `INSERT INTO V_STUDENTS`, but if v_students does not exist yet, your PL/SQL block will be invalid. You'd have to have dynamic SQL there, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Just try to create the table and then catch the exception if it already exists.
2. Your DDL statement is `'CREATE TABLE V_STUDENTS AS SELECT * FROM V_STUDENTS WHERE 1=2; ';` If `v_students` does not exist then you cannot select from it to create it; you need to select from an existing table such as `students`. (Also the trailing semi-colon is a syntax error in a dynamic SQL statement and should be removed.)
3. If the table does not exist when the statement is compiled then you will get a compile-time error if you try to insert into a non-existent table. If you are using dynamic SQL to create the table then you also need to use dynamic SQL to perform the insert.
4. You do not need to use cursors; just use `INSERT ... SELECT ...`
5. Catching the `OTHERS` exception is considered bad practice. Explicitly catch the exceptions you expect to be throw (like a table already existing when you try to create it) and don't catch all the other exceptions so that if something unexpected happens then you know about it.

Like this:

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE
    table_already_exists EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(table_already_exists, -955);
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE V_STUDENTS AS SELECT * FROM students WHERE 1=2';
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN table_already_exists THEN
      NULL;
  END;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
   'INSERT INTO v_students
    SELECT *
    FROM   students
    ORDER BY student_marks DESC
    FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY';
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IsCK-shu)

Comment: @MTO : I wan to perform insert using cursor how to do that. can you demonstrate that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1:

```
v_sql := 'CREATE TABLE V_STUDENTS AS SELECT * FROM ' || v_table_name || ' WHERE 1=2; ';
```

will produce

```
v_sql := 'CREATE TABLE V_STUDENTS AS SELECT * FROM V_STUDENTS WHERE 1=2; ';
```

There should not be a semi-colon in that statement after the `2`, and you can't create a table that doesn't exist by selecting from a table that doesn't exist. This will generate multiple runtime errors.

Problem 2:

```
INSERT INTO V_STUDENTS VALUES ...
```

Your insert statements will generate multiple compile-time errors (exactly as shown), if the `V_STUDENTS` table doesn't already exist.

Comment: The insert statement is not working ... remaining all i have fixed

Comment: The insert statement can't compile if the table doesn't already exist at compile time.